# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference (on release only)

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I'm using Kotlin in my project. I'm getting this error only on the release version. In the debug version, everything works perfectly. It happens on this line:

```kotlin
postList.addAll(response.body()!!.data)
```

I previously initialized it like this:

```kotlin
val postList: MutableList<Post> = mutableListOf()
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the full code

```kotlin
    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        adapter = PostsAdapter(context!!, postList)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvPosts.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        rvPosts.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun getPosts(){

        swipToRefresh.isRefreshing = true

        disposable.add(
            apiService.getPostsFeed(
                Config.token)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<Response<PostData>>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: Response<PostData>) {
                        swipToRefresh.isRefreshing = false

                        when {
                            response.isSuccessful -> {
                                postList.clear()
                                if(response.body() != null){
                                    postList.addAll(response.body()!!.data)
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    noPostsLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                            }
                            response.code() == 404 -> {
                                noPostsLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                            else -> {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    getString(R.string.error_general_failure),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                                noPostsLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        Timber.d("onError ${e.message}")
                        swipToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                        if(!Config.isNetworkConnected(context!!)){
                            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.error_internet_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.error_server_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }

                })
        )

    }
```

Comment: Attach your code

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I attached it

Comment: Your response in release in null

Comment: Every settings you have done for debug, do for release

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin No, You're wrong. Even if the response is null. I'm checking if it is null before adding it. So it shouldn't show a crash. It will show empty page. No posts

Comment: Not the `Response` itself, but `response.body()!!.data` is possibly null. The first thing the `addAll()` method does is call `toArray()` on the passed `Collection`, and that would explain the given Exception.

Comment: postList.addAll(response.body()?.data?)

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. I got it now. You're totally right.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Thank you. I'll add that line. It should solve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome, but the question is why you have problem just in release one. I think your code had problem in debug but you hadn't known it

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I just figured it out. It was an issue with the proguard rules. I was missing dontwarn for models. I didn't added it because I was using SerializedName on every variable. I thought if I used it I don't have to exclude the models from the obfuscation. But what happened some pages was working perfectly and others not. After adding the models into the proguard rules all the issues disappeared.

Comment: Please attach your answer @Mike M.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) I didn't really do anything. I was just helping to clarify what MohammadMoeinGolchin was saying. Please feel free to accept their answer, if you like, and to ask them to add any details that you might think need to be included. Thank you, though. I really appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `postList.addAll(response.body()?.data?)` or `postList.addAll(response.body()!!.data?)`